# jquery ui datepicker option dateformat does not respond properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to use the jquery ui datepicker in order to pick months and years. After searching in sites i have created this function:

```
$(".datepickerSchedule").datepicker({
            showOn: "both",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "yy-mm",
            minDate: new Date(taskStartDate),
            showButtonPanel: true,  

            onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                function isDonePressed(){
                   return $('#ui-datepicker-div').html().indexOf('ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all ui-state-hover') > -1;
                }

                if (isDonePressed()){
                    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                }
            }

        }).focus(function(){
            $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();    
        });
```

So on focus i am hiding calendar and only when i press Done the first date of Month selected is set to Datepicker.

Afters choosing a month then the format is displayed properly as mm-yy.

But in my screen i am loading with thymeleaf dates from DB and there i have the problem cause the dateformat does not work apply and i am getting dates as yy-mm-dd. The model object that i am using to set the input has a Date variable (though it make me believe that it has a parsing problem cause the input type is text)

Also when i set the format as "mm-yy" datepicker does not recognize the date that exists already in the field and opens in current month so for example if i have 2017-11-01 , datepicker will open to March 2019(this does not happen if dateformat is "yy-mm-dd" but happens if it is "mm-yy" or "yy-mm")

Last part how can i exclude selection of month for a year? I know about specific dates but can i do if from reading on day to exclude the complete month?